# Does QueryFields mode in gorm ignore smart selecting?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm learning advanced query in gorm v2. Here comes a question.

[Smart Select in gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Smart-Select-Fields)

```golang
type User struct {
  ID     uint
  Name   string
  Age    int
  Gender string
  // hundreds of fields
}

type APIUser struct {
  ID   uint
  Name string
}

db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{
  QueryFields: true,
})
```

What is Query Fields mode standing for? Does it imply that `Find()` will ignore smart selecting and be compelled to select all fields' name? The official documentation lacks sufficient comparison, which has left me puzzled about this mode.

i.e. For these two queries, are they equivalent if QueryFields mode is activated?

`db.Find(&user)`

`db.Find(&apiUser)`

By the way, I understand the following code and clearly know what will happen if running this code.

```golang
db.Model(&User{}).Limit(10).Find(&APIUser{})
// SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users` LIMIT 10
```